# SQL parser library for Java

Tags: java, sql, parsing

Is there an open-source Java library for parsing SQL statements?

If possible, it should be customizable or flexible enough to also be able to parse (or at least ignore) vendor-specific syntax (such as Oracle tablespace definitions or MySQL's LIMIT clause).

If not, strict adherence to the SQL standard is also fine.

**Update:** I need this for two things:

- providing an SQL interface to a non-SQL database (mapping to internal API calls)
- rewriting SQL before it goes to the actual database (e.g. Oracle)

Comment: how is this question not constructive? what's wrong with you, Stackoverflow?

Comment: This question should be reopened.  Also, found http://foundationdb.github.io/sql-parser/

Comment: This is off-topic - requests for libraries, tools, tutorials and other off-site resources are not considered on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I think this should be asked on another SE site

Comment: I think this question is constructive!!

Comment: Just in case anyone needs a more feature rich parser that is open source, supports multiple dialects, AST / visitors, checkout Alibaba's Druid: https://github.com/alibaba/druid/tree/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/sql

Comment: [jOOQ has a parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/). You can test it online, here: https://www.jooq.org/translate. It can be used to rewrite your SQL.

Answer (score 54):

[ANTLR3](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html) has an ANSI SQL grammar available.  You can use that to create your own parser.

ANTLR4 has a [SQL grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sqlite/SQLite.g4).

Comment: Why use ANTLR when you can implement your own parser generator?

Comment: Why generate your own parser generator when you can use ANTLR?

Comment: Any links to how one can use Antlr SQL Grammar to parse these queries? I looked at the grammar of some PL/SQL Parsers as well as Lexers and Parsers but was unable to fathom how to use one. Would appreciate any links.

Comment: You feed the grammar to ANTLR, which spits out the lexer/parser classes that you'll then compile and run.  The best source I can think of is the ANTLR reference: http://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Antlr-Reference-Domain-Specific-Programmers/dp/0978739256/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327847925&sr=8-1

Comment: We're up to ANTLR 4 now.  Perhaps the old grammars don't run on the new version.

Comment: @SHC see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14465585/268066

Comment: Careful though, the available grammars are not necessarily under the same license as ANTLR

Comment: ANTLR is great and nice to use but very slow, there's probably faster ones out there

Comment: Such as?   A recommendation or faster code from you would be more helpful.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 not seeing your point.  How is this comment on a 14 year old question advancing anything?  Is this the best you can come up with after 11 years on this site?

Comment: @duffymo Why should I advance anything other than my own intellect and well being? Don't get easily triggered, and especially after 14 years. :)

Comment: Fail to see how your comments advance anything.  Your rep isn't much to show after 11 years of effort, so it's not a surprise.

Answer (score 40):

- [JSqlParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser)
- [Trino's parser](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/tree/master/core/trino-parser) is written using ANTLR4 and has its own immutable AST classes that are built from the parser. The AST has a visitor and pretty printer.

Comment: I have a question for Presto, If I have Statement statement = SQL_PARSER.createStatement(query); How can I get the Query body, i.e. the Select, From, Where, etc values?

Comment: Statement is a base class. A SELECT statement will be of type Query. It contains a QueryBody that has the subclass QuerySpecification. The structure is more complex than you might expect in order to support UNION, TABLE, VALUES, set operations, etc. You can create a visitor by extending AstVisitor or DefaultTraversalVisitor. Look at SqlFormatter for an example of how to walk the tree.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the query tree structure from a given query using Presto?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you create a new question with more detail?

Answer (score 9):

**Parser**

If you need a parser there should be a parser in the code base of [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

**Dealing with vendor-specific SQL**

You may want to look at the [.native()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#nativeSQL(java.lang.String)) method on the jdbc Connection object which you can pass it vendor neutral queries that will get postprocessed into vendor specific queries.

Comment: That native() method looks interesting. Are there any examples as to how it can be used? What kind of conversions are possible there?

Comment: @Thilo e.g. [SQL Server 2014, nativeSQL Method (SQLServerConnection)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378174%28v=sql.110%29.aspx): _"This method is not currently supported by the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server."_

Comment: @Thilo OJDBC's [OracleConnectionWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnectionWrapper.html#nativeSQL_java_lang_String_) seems like supporting it.

Answer (score 7):

[General SQL Parser for Java](http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-java.php) is not open source, but is exactly what you are looking after.

Comment: The best sql parser for Java +1

Comment: surprised no one mention https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser.git , this is the most comprehensive sql parser I've seen

Answer (score 6):

Try

- [Zql](http://zql.sourceforge.net/) (Original Sourceforce)
- [Zql](https://github.com/mysearchdev/zql) (Github)
- [Zql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dev.mysearch/dev.mysearch.zql.parser/) (Maven Central)

Comment: zql is good for basic queries but when you try to parse a query that contains join statement, it blows up. so i don't suggest it

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate uses ANTLR for sql and hql parsing.

JSqlParser is also a good option.although it has some bugs(or some features not implemented) while parsing oracle pl/sql.
see its forum for detail.

so if you're parsing oracle pl/sql, ANTLR is recommended.

Comment: btw, anltr is under BSD.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do with the parsed SQL? I can recommend a few Java implementation of Lex/Yacc ([BYACC/J](http://byaccj.sourceforge.net/), [Java Cup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/)) that you can use an existing SQL grammar with.

If you want to actually do something with the resulting parsed grammar, I might suggest looking at [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), an open source SQL database written in Java.

Comment: Is the SQL parser used in Derby available as an independent JAR ?

Comment: I don't know. I've never looked at the source for Derby.

Comment: I now know the answer to this question: No, the SQL parser for Derby isn't a separate project. You will need pull it apart to use it for something other than Derby.

Comment: I came back again after 10 years :-)