# SQL - Parsing a query

Tags: sql

I worked on a parser for arithmetic expressions. 
The key there was building a syntax tree, where leaves are variables and nodes are operators.

Not I'm thinking about parsing SQL queries. Parsing simple select won't be a problem, but I'm not pretty sure about the complex queries.
Can you point me to a good reference about sql parsing. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [SQL BNF grammars](http://savage.net.au/SQL/)

Answer (score 2):

*Some codesamples:*
Look at sourceforge [Open SQL parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osqlp/).
There was a question for [sql parser library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java) before. Look there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you know C# or .NET, but [LinqToSql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) basically does this by building [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882636.aspx) that are then executed only when the query is 'called'.