# How to validate sql query syntax?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, validation

java 1.4
Sql server 2000

i am taking input of sql query (for validation of field value against values retrieved by executing sql query) from admin user which will be stored in database and later i will executing sql query corresponding to field.Before inserting sql query in database i want to validate its syntax in java code.

```
Fields         Sql Query

stateCode      select statecode from states
district code  select district code from districts
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dont think there is any (easy) way to validate sql

Sql syntax is complex and allows for alot of different ways to enter a statement.

Think you best shot would be to just execute the sql statent and if you have a SQl exception see if its a bad syntax thats causing it.

you can prepend some sql to avoid from actually executing the query

in sybase it would be
SET NOEXEC ON

Answer (score 9):

Create a [PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)) with the query string; if this works, the query string is ok (but nothing is executed yet)

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires a connection, this will not work in unit tests.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 The question is not about unit tests.That said, why can't you have a database connection when doing unit tests?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you let them enter whole sql-statements?

Just provide to fields and let them enter either the statecode or the districtcode.

Then check if the entered value is a number. And run the appropriate query with the entered value.

Comment: its not specific.table name and column can be  anything with some conditions or joins depending upon type of field.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would could be to get the explain plan of the query, if it manages to explain the query I guess it must be valid. Down side is that it won't like parametrised queries.

Comment: how to get explain plan of a query?

Comment: that's a very good question. haven't a clue how to do it on sql-server, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You could do SET FMTONLY ON and then execute the query and see if it works. Just remember to do SET FMTONLY OFF in a finally block, since it's a connection-level setting.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a full SQL Parser to do such a vendor-specific offline SQL syntax check.

Take a look at [this demo](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/vendor-specific-offline-sql-syntax-check/) which including some Java and C# code:

http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/vendor-specific-offline-sql-syntax-check/