# flow chart for an application made in swing

Tags: java, swing, flowchart, flow-diagram

- Basically, I have **2 text areas** and a **button** in swing frame

  - user will **enter sql query**(only a couple of variates of select and update m checking) in **jtextArea1**
  - on clicking button, the query will be checked syntactically and semantically
  - the output ie. syntax error or semantic error or the result in case of correct 
    query(i'll simply execute the query using StatementObject.executeQuery() in case it has no syntax and semantic error) will be displayed in **jtextArea2** using setText().

I've used java here ,netbeans as IDE and Excel

i just pick up the query from jtextArea1 using getText(),save it in a string and split it into tokens using split() of String.After this i just check whether the structure is correct using if-else-if and then i check whether table name,column name of given query exist in db or not. After this I check whether value assigned using set or checked using where(ie name="abc") is of the same type as specified.

**PS-**

- i have not used any grammar for this purpose.
- i have made only a **single class** with multiple methods performing the above defined task.

so here is my **question**

- what type of flow chart is suitable for representing the application design. Is something else too required if I am asked to explain the application design of it. How can the flow chart be made. How should I include the method names and class name along with their short description in the flow chart.

Comment: Excel is **not** a database. Also "what name should I assign to this application?" -- Really??

Comment: Anyways, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599547/how-to-validate-sql-query-syntax

Comment: your split regex better be pretty fancy, you can't just split on " ". That's why grammars/parsers were invented.