# Regular Expression Solution in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, split

i am new on Regular Expression.

I will test a String, wheter it is valid with a regular expression.

MY String is following:

```
`Select * from xddf_db.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename like '%[ABC]'` .... can several times on the end with and/or
```

It can begin als with Select name must not with *

```
`Select Name` .....
```

The important is that the bracket fields should begin and end with '[sdf]' or never with apostroph for exampe [sdf] that is correct too. But it is not allowed to begin with apostroph and not end. For example  '[asd] That should wrong.

The underline charcters "_" can in it but not must.

It is correct between/ Or not with apostroph. The fields can have have one percent symbol(it is for Like function).  For Example it is correct '%[asd]' or  %[asd]& correct toobe . That is correct too '[asd]%'  but that is wrong:  '%%[sdđ]%' . Only one it is allowed.  I hope you can help we with this hard expression.

---

Here is the list:

Allowed:

```
Select * from xddf_db.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename like '%[ABC]'
Select * from xddf_db.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename like '%[ABC]&'
Select * from xddf_db.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename like '[ABC]&'
Select Name from xddfdb.yyy where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename_abc ='[ABC]'
Select Name from xddfdb.yyy where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename_abc =[ABC]
Select * from xddfdb.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename_abc =[ABC]
Select * from xddfdb.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename_abc =[ABC] or post_dd like '%[ABC]'
Select * from xddfdb.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename_abc =[ABC] or post_dd < [ABC] and post_dd > [ABD]
```

WRONG

```
Select * from xddfdb.yyy_tte where adress = [PARAM]' and surename_abc = '[ABC]
Select * from xddf_db.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename like '%[ABC]&&'
Select Name from xddf_db.yyy_tte where adress = '[PARAM]' and surename like '%&[ABC]&&'
```

Comment: Sorry, but alone your question is really hard to read. I would suggest that you put your POSITIVE / NEGATIVE examples on single lines, and like one example for each of the conditions. Beyond that: not everything can or should be solved used regular expressions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1600061/982149 I guess you are trying to validate for correct SQL syntax ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any Java libraries out there that validate SQL syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax)

Comment: And I agree with Fildor: don't start to create your OWN SQL parser replacement. Better look for re-using an existing solution; instead of re-inventing your own (most likely **deficient**) wheel.

Comment: Something like `^(?!.*'[^'\s]+(?:\s|$))(?!.*(?:%%|&&))(?i)select.*from.*where.*$` if you persist on using regex for such validation of a SQL.