# parsing string according to oracle operators with regex

Tags: java, regex, oracle, operators

Basically I was trying to replace the part of string with its actual value which comes immediately after oracle operators. I can do this for limited operators list like `{=,>,<}` but I wonder that is there any way out to gather all the operators rather than giving them by hands? For instance, I have this string; `"a = xyz"`, then I will replace `xyz` with lets say `3`. But as you know we have bunch of operator namely `"like,in,exists etc"`. So my string can also be this: `"a like xyz"`.

So what do you suggest me?

Thanks.

Comment: So basically you're writing your own Oracle SQL statement parser? You'd better have a pretty good reason.

Answer (score 1):

> So what do you suggest me?

I suggest not to do this with regex (regex are not able to do so), but use an existing, proven SQL parser.

Have a look at this question on SO: [SQL parser library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

Make your job simpler - require a very strict syntax on behalf of the caller.

For example, require that the string be in the form "target operator #variable#", e.g. "`a = #xyz#`".

Then, all you need to do is use `REPLACE(input, '#xyz#', 3)`.

As noted above, you probably don't want to reinvent the Oracle SQL statement parser.