# Parser to parse an SQL query and return the column name's and the corresponding table name in Java

Tags: java, sql, parsing, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL parser library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java)

I need a parser that should return me column names with their corresponding table names in the format

> column_name table_name

Preferably a java library, that can make the implementation easier as I dont want to get into all the nuances of SQL parsing.

regards,

Comment: What if there are multiple columns in the SQL query? Are they to be delimited with CRLF?

Comment: There's already [a question asked on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881893/need-java-api-to-parse-sql-statements), why did you ask the same again?

Comment: @ vineet That question was put earlier with lesser requirements.I have checked out the ZQL library and in fact made an application on it when this new requirement of matching the column names with the table names was obtained. The intention was to leave the old question as it is , because the question was answered in the best possible way . And put this slightly advanced requirement in a different question and nothing else.

Comment: I'm afraid the same answers will hold good. You don't need a different API/library for this purpose than the ones suggested already.

Comment: @vineet most of the libraries obtained earlier especially the ZQL which i have tried out returns column names and table names seperately and I dont know a way of matching them.

Comment: Like I suggested in the duffymo's answer in your other question. Use ANTLR, you'll need to hook into the appropriate parts of the parser, to collect this information so that you can return the desired structure. The not-so-important fact is that all parsers will parse your input if they can understand the grammar; the important part of your solution is whether you can hook into the parser and store state.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a connection to the database, you can do that using a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "....";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSetMetaData meta = pstmt.getMetaData();
```

Then you can use [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) and [`getColumnName(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName%28int%29) to retrieve the column names. If your JDBC driver supports it, you can even get the underlying table name using [`getTableName(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName%28int%29)

Note that not all drivers support getting the metadata before actually executing the statement, you need to test that with the one you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!
I have just performed some google search and found the following interesting references:

[SQL parser library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java)

http://www.gibello.com/code/zql/

http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-java.php

I hope this helps.

Comment: A more feature rich SQL parser that allows for other dialects is Alibaba's Druid: https://github.com/alibaba/druid/tree/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/sql.