# get table name from query

Tags: java, regex

My question should be simple for many of you
Supouse I have the following SQL and I want to get the table name using regexp:

```
SELECT name, age FROM table1
```

Using this expression I can get that ok

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*FROM\\s+(.*?)($|\\s+[WHERE,JOIN,START\\s+WITH,ORDER\\s+BY,GROUP\\s+BY])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher result = p.matcher(pSql);
        if (result.find()) {
            lRetorno = result.group(1);
        }
```

But, in case the table name contains the schema name (xyz.table1) my expression brings everything. My question is ... what do I need to modify on this query to only return me the table name without schema/owner?

Any help would be extremely apreciated
Regards

Raphael Moita

Comment: when you have more than one table (joins) what do you expect?

Comment: I expect to get the table name from the second query. I do that putting .* in front of the expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try it this way

```
String data1="SELECT name, age FROM table1 whatever";
String data2="SELECT name, age FROM schema.table1 whatever";

Pattern p=Pattern.compile("from\\s+(?:\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)($|\\s+[WHERE,JOIN,START\\s+WITH,ORDER\\s+BY,GROUP\\s+BY])",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

//test
Matcher m=p.matcher(data1);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
m=p.matcher(data2);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

output:

```
table1 
table1
```

### Edit

I just realized that part `($|\\s+[WHERE,JOIN,START\\s+WITH,ORDER\\s+BY,GROUP\\s+BY])` doesn't work as it should because in my input i placed "whatever" after table name and it was found anyway.

It doesn't work like you because you are using `[WHERE,JOIN,START\\s+WITH,ORDER\\s+BY,GROUP\\s+BY]` instead of `(WHERE|JOIN|START\\s+WITH|ORDER\\s+BY|GROUP\\s+BY)`. For example `[abc]` is equal to (a|b|c) so it says regular expression engine to accept any character from that set, not a word `abc`. Improve your pattern to something like

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("from\\s+(?:\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)(\\s*$|\\s+(WHERE|JOIN|START\\s+WITH|ORDER\\s+BY|GROUP\\s+BY))",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Pshemo: it works fine, thanks buddy! Would you mind to explain me what exactely (?:\\w+\\.)*(\\w+) does? What does this colon in front the question mark is doing there?

Comment: Group with `?:` at the beginning will not be counted. Thanks to that I was able to call `m.group(1)` always, even if there was some data in `(?:\\w+\\.)`.

Comment: You make me think ... I don't need to control any set of words like I was doing [WHERE|JOIN|START ..., I just need to figure out where is the end of the table name: Pattern p=Pattern.compile(".*FROM\\s+(?:\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)(\\s*$|\\s+\\w+)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); Right?!

Comment: Let me make other question ... I just realized that I also need to remove the table alias from the column names (SELECT xyz.name, xyz.age FROM table1 xyz). I'm doing that using two extra steps: "result.group(1).replaceAll("\\w+\\.", "").replaceAll("(\\s+,|,\\s+)", ",")". Do you think I could do it in one shot changing something on the main expression?

Comment: If the way you are replacing it now works for you and you understand how it works then I would leave it that way. But if you insists to replace it in one `replaceAll` method you can try something like this `replaceAll("\\w+\\.|(?<=,)\\s+|\\s+(?=,)", "")`. To understand `(?<=,)\\s+` or `\\s+(?=,)` read [this grate tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: This regex does not works. Checked in https://regex101.com/

Comment: @mohorchatt Could you share link with examples? Something like https://regex101.com/r/3erxQq/1 (you need to use "save regex" option to generate such link when you are ready).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than parsing with a regular expression, you might have a better time using an actual parser.  See this related question [Need java API to parse SQL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881893/need-java-api-to-parse-sql-statements) which recommends the [Zql](http://zql.sourceforge.net/) library.

It's got [examples of the queries it can parse](http://zql.sourceforge.net/ztest.html) that seem at least as robust as any regex you're going to write.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sqlQueryString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
ZqlParser parser = new ZqlParser(is);
ZQuery query = (ZQuery)parser.readStatement();
Vector tables = query.getFrom();
```

should do it for you.  `tables` is a `Vector` of `ZFromItem`s, and you can do `getTable()` on one to get its name without the schema component.

Comment: Looks good, but it doesn't look like it understands the JOIN clauses. Have you been able to get around that?

Comment: It is not at all supporting mysql functions like "YEAR", "select *".