# Parse SQL query in Java with UTF-8 support

Tags: java, sql, parsing

What (tool, library, way) can you recommend for parsing SQL query in Java?
I need to change column names in output, so for example:
I want to change query from:

> SELECT a AS one, b AS two FROM xyz ORDER BY 1

to

> SELECT a AS one_1, b AS two_2 FROM xyz ORDER BY 1

There might be many queries in one file to parse.

I tried using JSqlParser, but it doesn't support UTF-8 in SQL statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java

Comment: Try out.. [ZQL parser](http://zql.sourceforge.net/). its free to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSqlParser](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/) comes to mind. Never used it, but seems to fit the bill pretty well.