# SQL parsing in Java

Tags: java, sql

I have to parse the `SQL DDL` queries to validate the `SQL` using Java.

I tried and found some of the tools like `jsql, ZSql`.

I downloaded `ZSQL` tool but struck with configuring.

Is there any other easy way to parse the DDL command SQL file ?

`ZSQL` or `JSQL` parsing means let me know the steps to configure in Windows XP.

Comment: You should probably post your conifg and tell where are you stuck at. Escaping to some other framework is not the best strategy to solve your problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any Java libraries out there that validate SQL syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a really straightforward way to do this in Java. There are some related questions [How to validate sql query syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599547/how-to-validate-sql-query-syntax) and [Any Java libraries out there that validate SQL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax).

Many applications do not expose the ability to create raw SQL statements (for various reasons - security concerns, simplicity, etc), but rather expose the fields necessary to create the statement, and then the application generates the SQL under the hood.

If you do need to create a full blown SQL parser, then I suggest looking at tools that are designed to do parsing. ANTLR is a common tool implementing a parser in java. There are grammars that exist for ANTLR3 for SQL but not yet for ANTLR4 - [antlr4 sql grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464372/antlr4-sql-grammar).

Comment: let me see thanks Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You could use General SQL Parser Java Version (http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-java.php)

Comment: I have gone through that sqlParser.It is shareware , so i just trying to work on ZSQL and JSQL parser. You have any ideas on  ZSQL means share with me