# I Have a database in ".Sql" format. I would like to convert this database to ".sqlite" format .in runtime

Tags: android, database

I Have a database in ".Sql" format on my local server . I would like to convert this database to ".sqlite" for my android matchine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hier a list of converters for you

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

you can convert them in your server and download the .sqlite file in your phone

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the sql file and execute queries in the onCreate method on SQLiteOpenHelper class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java) is some help to parse the sql file.