# Anybody knows if exists an open-source SQL parser?

Tags: java, sql, parsing, sql-parser

I'm searching an open source SQL parser written in Java. I founded only this commercial software that satisfy my requires: http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-java.php

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/660609/373334

Answer (score 0):

jsqlparser parses an SQL statement and translate it into a hierarchy of Java classes. http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

May I add the active developed fork of JSQLParser at https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser.