# Get referenced Views and Tables in SQL via regex

Tags: sql, regex, parsing

I am creating some SQL tables and views. Most of them contain dependencies to others. I want to check these dependencies and retrieve a chronological order in which the tables or views have to be created...

So, basically, what I want to do is to extract all View or Table names from an SQL script in Java. I am using a pattern matcher and regex. Works so far, but I can't find the correct regex.

Take a look at this example SQL script:

```
Select * from view_1; select abc, bda from view_2, view_3 v8, view_4 where whatever;
select * from view_5 join view_6 where whatever; 
select v6.abc, v7.bda from view_7 v6 join view_8 v7;
select abc from

view9

,

view10,

view11;

select abcd from view12 v   
, view13 s;
```

What I want to extract is a list which contains view 1 to 13.
(view1, view2, ..., view13)

I already tried

```
(?<=(from|join))\s+\w+((\s+\w+)?)(\s*,\s*\w+(\s+\w+)?)*
```

But that didn't work as expected.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to parse this with a single regular expression to parte tables and views after the `from` keyword. To parse `join` expressions is easier. I suggest you to use Divide and Conquer approach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Henrique that regex probably isn't the way to go here (unless you can assume simple SQL statements). Perhaps use a SQL parser. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java) asks about SQL parsers for Java. I took a look at one and found an [example](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/example.php) that finds tables referenced in a select statement.