# How can I detect the presence of SQL code, in a page of android code?

Tags: java, android, sql, regex, sqlite

> The purpose of this question, is **not** to figure out how to prevent SQL Injection attempts.
>
> Instead I would like to know, how to detect lines of SQL code within an
>   (*Android Class*) file

Unlike other SQL parser threads I am wanting to work within **Android** and I am simply after something like a **Regex statement** which could be used to detect SQL code within the current line

I have an **example** page of **Android** code like the below :

```
String query = "select * from users_table where username = '" +  u_username + "' and password = '" + u_password +"'";
SQLiteDatabase db
//some un-important code here...
Cursor c = db.rawQuery( p_query, null );
return c.getCount() != 0;
}
```

Within which there are a lines of **SQL** code like:

```
select * from users_table where username = '" +  u_username + "' and password = '" + u_password +"'
```

I have a function like the below, which reads in an (*Android Class*) file line by line. Then returns an ArrayList of String.

```
public ArrayList<String> SQLStatementsfromFile(File fileLocation) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> SQLStatements = new ArrayList<>();
    FileInputStream is;
    BufferedReader reader;
    if (fileLocation.exists()) {
        is = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            line = reader.readLine();

            if (line != null) {
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {

                    if (line.contains(SQL))
                    SQLStatements.add(line);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return SQLStatements;
}
```

What I would like to know is: are there any sort of possible *Regex* statements (or other code detection methods) which could be used to detect SQL code, from each line of android code (so it can be added to the ArrayList *SQLStatements*)?

---

To be clear, **PLEASE** do not give me tips on example code I have written above.

Or advice on examples given. Just **PLEASE** instead attempt to actually answer my question.

I know parameter-ised statements within SQL etc. are much more secure, but this is **NOT** why I have opened this thread, the above are simply examples of SQL code I would like to be detect (**NOT** SQL code I plan to utilize).

Thank you :-)

Comment: Do not use Regex or any other technique to determine presence of SQL code in the input, **instead use parameterized queries**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL parser library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming any **valid** SQL statement has to start with `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` or `DELETE`and end with a semicolon `;`, you can find sql using the following:

```
/(?:INSERT INTO|UPDATE|SELECT|DELETE)(?:[^;'"]|(?:'[^']*?')|(?:"[^"]*?"))+;/i
```

So first off, the sql you wrote is not what I consider valid, as it lacks the ending semicolon.

If you can ensure the synax of sql follows the rules I stated earlier, the `;` to end Java code lines shouldn't interfere with this regex.

Without the semicolon, your example code does not match, but insert the semicolon and it does. Example here:

https://regex101.com/r/zB2yJ1/1

Comment: SQL does not require a semicolon; it's used only for *separating* statements.

Comment: It's part of the ANSI SQL-92 standard, but some flavors of SQL may not require them. Why on earth you would write SQL without a terminator, I do not know. Even the flavors that allow you to use SQL without one, **may** fail without one in certain cases. Anyway, I posted the regex under the assumption that you do have a semicolon, simply removing it from the regex works just fine.

Comment: The syntax rules for `<direct SQL statement>` indeed require a semicolon, but you cannot rely on any random Java code to actually use it.

Comment: Sure, and then you have an unreliable pattern. It works without it, as I said, but it's far less certain you will actually find SQL.