# Parse SQL Script to extract table and column names

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server, parsing

If I have a SQL script is there a way to parse and extract the columns and tables referenced in the script into a table like structure :

Script:

```
Select t1.first, t1.last, t2.car, t2.make, t2.year
from owners t1
left join cars t2
on t1.owner_id = t2.owner_id
```

Output:

```
Table   Column
owners  first
owners  last
owners  owner_id
cars    car
cars    make
cars    year
cars    owner_id
```

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible or whether there is an easy way? Unless you can limit the input to a simple and strict subset of the grammar, you would have to define the grammar for SELECT and its associated expressions... http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#select

Comment: @THK I guess both.  Just seems like this happens somewhere in the sql execution process and was curious if someone had turned it into a library.

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, there don't seem to be any standalone parsers widely accepted as authoritative. There are some SO threads about the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java. Python has the sqlparse library but it does not validate grammar.

Comment: Please let me know if you found some solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but interesting so here it goes - turn your script temporarily into a stored procedure forcing SQL Server to map the dependencies and then you can retrieve them by using:

```
SELECT referenced_entity_name ,referenced_minor_name FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.stp_ObjectsToTrack', 'Object')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want in SQL Server:

```html
select t.name as [Table], c.name as [Column]
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t
on c.object_id = t.object_id
```

Comment: The logic/relationships need to be extracted from the script / query itself, not the system tables.

Comment: Sometimes the names of the columns are not the same, so it's going to be hard.