# Android: SQL Parameter Evaluator for Realm

Tags: java, android, sql, realm

I need to translate SQL statement to Realm (to get record stored in Realm based on SQL statement). I just need to handle ***SELECT*** statement with SQL parameters and translate it to Realm. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE (Name = 'John Doe' OR Name = 'Joe Black') AND (Postcode = '10013')
```

I need to evaluate anything after ***WHERE*** statement so I can filter and return appropriate records. So, from example above, it is translated to Realm like this

```
realm.where(tblCustomer.class)
     .beginGroup()
          .equalTo("Name", "John Doe")
          .or()
          .equalTo("Name", "Joe Black")
     .endGroup()
     .beginGroup()
          .equalTo("Postcode", "10013")
     .endGroup();
```

I have tried to use Dijsktra's algorithm ([Evaluate.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/Evaluate.java.html)) to evaluate the *WHERE* parameters, but I am having problem with *translating spaces*.

I am just wondering, does anyone have algorithms ready to evaluate SQL parameters? If yes, I'll just use your algorithm instead of creating one myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Um. You know Realm is not relational (as it is an object store), and also a NoSQL database, right? You'll run into trouble with HAVING, GROUPBY, projection for "not *", and JOINs.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just need to evaluate simple SQL condition. I don't even need to worry about IN operator.

Comment: Btw, EpicPandaForce, you are awesome!!! Thanks for editing my question. I didn't know about beginGroup()! You are the best!

Comment: Basically what you need is a SQL parser. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660609/sql-parser-library-for-java or just search for “sql parser".

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, your answer is excellent, but why you wrote it inside to the question?

Comment: @Sergey because it doesn't answer his question, so it's a comment.

Comment: @beeender, this is exactly what I am looking for. please post it as answer and I'll accept your answer. Thanks!